# proxycommand doesnt seem to work with ansible and my environment

Tags: ssh, ansible

I've tried many combinations to get this to work but cannot for some reason. I am not using keys in our environment so passwords will have to do.

I've tried proxyjump and sshuttle as well.

It's strange has the ping module works but when trying another module or playbook it doesn't work.

Rough set up is:

- laptop running ubuntu with ansible installed

[laptop] ---> [productionjumphost] ---> [production_iosxr_router]

**ansible.cfg:**

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-%r@%h:%p -F ssh.config
```

**~/.ssh/config == ssh.cfg: (configured both)**

```
Host modeljumphost
  HostName modeljumphost.fqdn.com.au
  User user
  Port 22

Host productionjumphost
  HostName productionjumphost.fqdn.com.au
  User user
  Port 22

Host model_iosxr_router
  HostName model_iosxr_router
  User user
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:22 modeljumphost

Host production_iosxr_router
  HostName production_iosxr_router
  User user
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:22 productionjumphost
```

**inventory:**

```
[local]
192.168.xxx.xxx

[router]
production_iosxr_router ansible_connection=network_cli ansible_user=user ansible_ssh_pass=password

[router:vars]
ansible_network_os=iosxr
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@productionjumphost.fqdn.com.au"'
ansible_user=user
ansible_ssh_pass=password
```

**playbook.yml:**

```
---

- name: Network Getting Started First Playbook
  hosts: router
  gather_facts: no
  connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: show version
      iosxr_command:
        commands: show version
```

I can run an ad-hoc ansible command and a successful ping is returned:

**result: ansible production_iosxr_router -i inventory -m ping -vvvvv**

```
production_iosxr_router | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    }, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

**running playbook: ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -vvvvv**

```
production_iosxr_router | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "[Errno -2] Name or service not known"
}
```

Comment: Did you use colon instead of equal inside the inventory file for ansible_ssh_common_args?

Comment: @HabeebPerwad I didn't think so. That might have come due to trying to remove details that shouldn't be in the public domain...however, just added all config files again and used equal instead of colon and got the following error: "msg": "Error reading SSH protocol banner" - thanks for your response btw

Comment: now i too got "Negotiation failed: Error reading SSH protocol banner". We are making progress :D

Comment: Look like my issue got resolved; not properly verified. Let me update you what I learnt so far so that you can make some progress. I was working for connection: netconfig.
I have to set "ansible_netconf_ssh_config:True" in /etc/ansible/hosts and add the ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config.  I didn't need to set ansible_ssh_common_args.

Comment: Few more things you can do in the jump/bastion host. Check the ssh log using the command **sudo journalctl -u ssh -f** and **sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log**

Comment: Once the ProxyCommand is working, you can have some fun in bastion host by running **watch -n 1 "netstat -tunapl | grep TARGET-IP"** to make sure it is really connecting through this bastion host :P

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for your help man, really appreciate it. Unfortunately, as this is the corp network, I don't have sudo rights on bastion host :( will keep checking stuff and your notes from above, thank u sir! :)